# highcharts columnas sin espacios entre si

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Tengo el siguiente código para la generación de un gráfico de columnas: https://jsfiddle.net/pamuro01/Lc7rd4z5/57/

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
    "series": [{
        "id": "FL",
        "name": "Lúmenes",
        "type": "line",
        "color": "rgb(255, 215, 0)",
        "lineWidth": 2,
        "dashStyle": "Solid",
        "data": [
          [1612926540000, 0],
          [1612926900000, 0],
          [1612927260000, 0],
          [1612927560000, 0],
          [1612927920000, 0],
          [1612928220000, 0],
          [1612928580000, 0],
          [1612928880000, 0],
          [1612929240000, 0],
          [1612929600000, 0],
          [1612929900000, 0],
          [1612930260000, 0],
          [1612930560000, 0],
          [1612930920000, 0],
          [1612931220000, 0],
          [1612931580000, 0],
          [1612931880000, 0],
          [1612932240000, 0],
          [1612932540000, 0],
          [1612932900000, 0],
          [1612933260000, 0],
          [1612933560000, 0],
          [1612933920000, 0],
          [1612934220000, 0],
          [1612934580000, 0],
          [1612934940000, 0],
          [1612935240000, 0],
          [1612935600000, 0],
          [1612935900000, 0],
          [1612936260000, 0],
          [1612936560000, 0],
          [1612936920000, 0],
          [1612937220000, 0],
          [1612937580000, 0],
          [1612937940000, 0],
          [1612938240000, 0],
          [1612938600000, 0],
          [1612938900000, 0],
          [1612939260000, 0],
          [1612939620000, 0],
          [1612939920000, 0],
          [1612940280000, 0],
          [1612940640000, 0],
          [1612940940000, 0],
          [1612941300000, 16],
          [1612941600000, 16],
          [1612941960000, 52],
          [1612942320000, 52],
          [1612942620000, 88],
          [1612942980000, 108],
          [1612943280000, 144],
          [1612943640000, 180],
          [1612944000000, 232],
          [1612944300000, 268],
          [1612944660000, 304],
          [1612944960000, 396],
          [1612945320000, 412],
          [1612945620000, 556],
          [1612945980000, 592],
          [1612946340000, 700],
          [1612946640000, 556],
          [1612947000000, 648],
          [1612947300000, 720],
          [1612947660000, 952],
          [1612948020000, 1152],
          [1612948320000, 1080],
          [1612948680000, 1152],
          [1612948980000, 1404],
          [1612949340000, 1656],
          [1612949700000, 1636],
          [1612950000000, 1548],
          [1612950360000, 1456],
          [1612950660000, 1780],
          [1612951020000, 1872],
          [1612951320000, 2124],
          [1612951680000, 2268],
          [1612952040000, 2268],
          [1612952340000, 3112],
          [1612952700000, 2520],
          [1612953060000, 2700],
          [1612953360000, 3636],
          [1612953720000, 4372],
          [1612954020000, 3240],
          [1612954380000, 3312],
          [1612954680000, 4464],
          [1612955040000, 4444],
          [1612955400000, 5292],
          [1612955700000, 4912],
          [1612956060000, 5128],
          [1612956360000, 5652],
          [1612956720000, 6084],
          [1612957080000, 6496],
          [1612957380000, 7704],
          [1612957740000, 7380],
          [1612958040000, 9952],
          [1612958400000, 8656],
          [1612958700000, 9952],
          [1612959060000, 10512],
          [1612959360000, 9720],
          [1612959720000, 8476],
          [1612960020000, 7828],
          [1612960380000, 7560],
          [1612960680000, 8712],
          [1612961040000, 9772],
          [1612961340000, 7792],
          [1612961700000, 9772],
          [1612962060000, 11752],
          [1612962360000, 16864],
          [1612962720000, 16308],
          [1612963020000, 13552],
          [1612963380000, 15480],
          [1612963680000, 15660],
          [1612964040000, 15768],
          [1612964340000, 15208],
          [1612964700000, 15480],
          [1612965000000, 16684],
          [1612965360000, 16128],
          [1612965660000, 16776],
          [1612966020000, 16596],
          [1612966320000, 19636],
          [1612966380000, 19636],
          [1612966680000, 16684],
          [1612966980000, 18340],
          [1612967340000, 18252],
          [1612967640000, 18252],
          [1612968000000, 17692],
          [1612968300000, 17044],
          [1612968660000, 17512],
          [1612968960000, 17332],
          [1612969320000, 15480],
          [1612969620000, 16776],
          [1612969980000, 17784],
          [1612970280000, 15768],
          [1612970640000, 18700],
          [1612970940000, 20644],
          [1612971300000, 18340],
          [1612971600000, 17224],
          [1612971960000, 18340],
          [1612972260000, 19080],
          [1612972620000, 18072],
          [1612972920000, 17424],
          [1612973280000, 18988],
          [1612973580000, 18612],
          [1612973940000, 19260],
          [1612974240000, 18700],
          [1612974600000, 16396],
          [1612974900000, 13464],
          [1612975200000, 13552],
          [1612975560000, 15028],
          [1612975860000, 11788],
          [1612976220000, 12436],
          [1612976520000, 11988],
          [1612976880000, 15208],
          [1612977180000, 16396],
          [1612977540000, 13732],
          [1612977840000, 17784],
          [1612978200000, 12816],
          [1612978500000, 11572],
          [1612978860000, 11572],
          [1612979160000, 9808],
          [1612979520000, 8008],
          [1612979820000, 7740],
          [1612980180000, 9160],
          [1612980480000, 7884],
          [1612980840000, 8208],
          [1612981140000, 6316],
          [1612981500000, 8388],
          [1612981800000, 6588],
          [1612982160000, 5940],
          [1612982460000, 5200],
          [1612982820000, 5200],
          [1612983120000, 4464],
          [1612983480000, 3348],
          [1612983780000, 3060],
          [1612984140000, 3204],
          [1612984440000, 3544],
          [1612984800000, 3040],
          [1612985100000, 2664],
          [1612985460000, 2304],
          [1612985820000, 1836],
          [1612986120000, 1672],
          [1612986480000, 1384],
          [1612986780000, 1240],
          [1612987140000, 916],
          [1612987440000, 828],
          [1612987800000, 684],
          [1612988100000, 520],
          [1612988460000, 432],
          [1612988820000, 304],
          [1612989120000, 216],
          [1612989480000, 124],
          [1612989780000, 72],
          [1612990140000, 36],
          [1612990440000, 16],
          [1612990800000, 0],
          [1612991100000, 0],
          [1612991460000, 0],
          [1612991820000, 0],
          [1612992120000, 0],
          [1612992480000, 0],
          [1612992780000, 0],
          [1612993140000, 0],
          [1612993440000, 0],
          [1612993800000, 0],
          [1612994160000, 0],
          [1612994460000, 0],
          [1612994820000, 0],
          [1612995120000, 0],
          [1612995480000, 0],
          [1612995780000, 0],
          [1612996140000, 0],
          [1612996440000, 0],
          [1612996800000, 0],
          [1612997100000, 0],
          [1612997460000, 0],
          [1612997820000, 0],
          [1612998120000, 0],
          [1612998480000, 0],
          [1612998780000, 0],
          [1612999140000, 0],
          [1612999500000, 0],
          [1612999800000, 0],
          [1613000160000, 0],
          [1613000460000, 0],
          [1613000820000, 0],
          [1613001120000, 0],
          [1613001480000, 0]
        ],
        "xAxis": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "BL",
        "name": "Acumulado total",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "rgb(255, 255, 0, 0.60)",
        "lineWidth": 2,
        "dashStyle": "Solid",
        "stack": "acumulado",
        "data": [
          [1612929600000, 0],
          [1612933200000, 0],
          [1612936800000, 0],
          [1612940400000, 0],
          [1612944000000, 3772],
          [1612947600000, 15688],
          [1612951200000, 34016],
          [1612954800000, 63044],
          [1612958400000, 98752],
          [1612962000000, 168884],
          [1612965600000, 213752],
          [1612969200000, 196208],
          [1612972800000, 175648],
          [1612976400000, 136624],
          [1612980000000, 70696],
          [1612983600000, 24864],
          [1612987200000, 2032],
          [1612990800000, 0],
          [1612994400000, 0],
          [1612998000000, 0]
        ],
        "xAxis": 1,
        "yAxis": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "UL",
        "name": "Nublado",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "rgb(155, 155, 155, 0.70)",
        "lineWidth": 2,
        "dashStyle": "Solid",
        "stack": "acumulado",
        "data": [
          [1612929600000, 0],
          [1612933200000, 0],
          [1612936800000, 0],
          [1612940400000, 0],
          [1612944000000, 3772],
          [1612947600000, 15688],
          [1612951200000, 34016],
          [1612954800000, 63044],
          [1612958400000, 88240],
          [1612962000000, 0],
          [1612965600000, 0],
          [1612969200000, 0],
          [1612972800000, 0],
          [1612976400000, 25556],
          [1612980000000, 70696],
          [1612983600000, 24864],
          [1612987200000, 2032],
          [1612990800000, 0],
          [1612994400000, 0],
          [1612998000000, 0]
        ],
        "xAxis": 1,
        "yAxis": 1
      },
    ],
    "chart": {
      "zoomType": "xy"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Luminosidad"
    },
    "legend": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "tooltip": {
      "shared": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "borderColor": "#fff",
      "backgroundColor": "#fff"
    },
    "xAxis": [{
        "type": "datetime",
      },
      {
        "type": "datetime",
      },
    ],
    "yAxis": [{
        "opposite": true,
        "title": {
          "text": "Luxes"
        },
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Radiación Fotosintética"
        },
      }, ,
      {
        "opposite": true,
        "title": {
          "text": "Luz Acumulada"
        },
      },
    ],
    "plotOptions": {
      "column": {
        "stacking": "normal",
        "dataLabels": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "series": {
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "halo": {
              "size": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "line": {
        "marker": {
          "enabled": false,
          "lineColor": null,
          "states": {
            "hover": {
              "fillColor": "white",
              "radius": 5
            }
          },
          "symbol": "diamond"
        }
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

He buscado la forma de que el marguen o espacio entre columnas sea el mínimo, casi imperceptible, la idea es que el ancho de la columna abarque la hora completa que utiliza el gráfico de línea, 12:00 A 12:59 por ejemplo.

He probado definir el ancho de las columnas pero el problema es que según la resolución del desktop o celular las columnas se superponen.

Gracias de antemano.